# Best Config after Hyperparameter Search with Ray Tune

Tags: ray, ray-tune

I just run my first Ray Tune. I got nice terminal output an all that but now I'm wondering: Which configuration gave me the best score?

I see that there are a ton of results files but is there an easy way to get the best config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ExperimentAnalysis` object returned by `tune.run()` to get the best config, like this:

```
analysis = tune.run(trainable, search_alg=algo, stop={"training_iteration": 20})

best_trial = analysis.best_trial  # Get best trial
best_config = analysis.best_config  # Get best trial's hyperparameters
best_logdir = analysis.best_logdir  # Get best trial's logdir
best_checkpoint = analysis.best_checkpoint  # Get best trial's best checkpoint
best_result = analysis.best_result  # Get best trial's last results
best_result_df = analysis.best_result_df  # Get best result as pandas dataframe
```

See the documentation: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/key-concepts.html#analysis

Comment: Ah yeah I saw that. Got confused but seems like that analysis object is shared between all runs.

Comment: How to do this if I did not save the analysis object? But I have all the result.json files and tfevent logs?

Comment: @xotix how did you resolve it ?

Comment: @LearnToGrow Can't remember but apparently using the solution above. I probably didn't use any files. You could ask in one of the Ray Tune's help channels.